# Closing QDialog from Mainwindow

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Mainwindow that creates a QDialog(that its name is qds) when I press a button.
When I close the Mainwindow, I want QDialog is closed too. But, when I close the Mainwindow, QDialog is still open and application is still running. 
This is the mainwindow's destructor:

```
MainWindow::~MainWindow(){
    if(qds) delete qds; // this is the QDialog
    // ...other code
}
```

qds is not mainwindow's child.
I tried with to put

```
setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
```

in mainwindow's constructor, but it generates segmentation faul(double free).

Comment: Did you remove `delete qds;` in the `setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);` case?

Comment: @LogicStuff yeah, but it's the same

Comment: Could you please show the code how you create the dialog?

Comment: @demonplus [pastebinlink](http://pastebin.com/489TvZwn) this is the whole qdialog_search class

Comment: Did you check if ~MainWindow() is actually called?

Comment: yeah i'm sure beacuse i put some output... ~QDialog_search() is called too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The non-modal dialog is launched and the pointer is in main window
>   object. It prevents the app from quitting while closing the main window. How to fix that?

The application event loop should not have more objects 'spinning' in it and that solves the problem. I call all the widgets that don't have  the other widget 'this' pointer passed via constructor 'detached'. But we can still track them. I use lists of 'detached' widgets but with just one 'detached' dialog the class member variable pointer is enough.

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
   // TODO: also make sure m_pDetachedNonmodalDlg set to null
   //       when the dialog closed on its own and deleted: see
   //       QObject::destroyed() signal for that or make it like
   //       QPointer<QWidget> m_pDetachedWidget
   if (m_pDetachedNonmodalDlg)
      m_pDetachedNonmodalDlg->close();

   // or event->accept(); but fine 'moments' are there
   QMainWindow::closeEvent(event);
}
```