# QDialog derived class

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog

I have derived class from QDialog that I use for showing the charts. The constructor looks like this:

```
myplot::myplot(QDialog *parent) : QDialog(parent)
{
    chartView = new QChartView();
    chart = new QChart();

    Qt::WindowFlags flags = 0;
    flags |= Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint;
    flags |= Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint;
    setWindowFlags(flags);

    this->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);
    this->layout()->addWidget(chartView);

    this->setModal(1);
    chartView->setChart(chart);
}
```

I call my class from Mainwindow.cpp but dialog does not close after App exit:

```
myplot* plot = new myplot();        //does not close after app exit
plot->do_something();
plot->show();
```

I thought I will correct the problem by this but it does not work:

```
myplot* plot = new myplot(this);    //does not work
```

When I use this the dialog is closed immediatelly

```
myplot plot;                //immediatelly close
plot.do_something();
plot.show();
```

When I use exec instead of `.show()` I get the error ***"Debug Assertion Failed, _CtrlIsValidHeapPointer(block)"*** after dialog is closed

```
plot.exec();

            //work but after exiting dialog error
```

Please, how to handle correctly my derived class to be closed after App exit? I also want to have `myplot` class to be not modal (now I have it modal in order the user would close it manually before app exit).

Added header file:

```
#ifndef MYPLOT_H
#define MYPLOT_H

class myplot : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
public:
    explicit myplot(QDialog *parent = nullptr);
signals:

};


#endif // MYPLOT_H
```

Comment: please show the header of the dialog....

Comment: I added header file (where I deleted for better readability some variables and methods that are not related to problem I believe).

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37486713/closing-qdialog-from-mainwindow) question.

The answer is you have to write that functionality yourself. If you have your `myplot` object as a member variable of your `MainWindow` class then you can properly close it in the `MainWindow::closeEvent`. See the linked answer above for a hint on how you might implement this.

BTW: Then you don't have to make your dialog modal to enforce closing it before the MainWindow.

Answer (score 0):

you need to look what the QDialog looks like...

do: pass a QWidget instead of a QDialog to the constructor, add a destructor to the dialog and delete there all the things created by the myplot instance if any, call exec() instead of show()...

```
class myplot : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit myplot(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
         ~myplot();
    ....
```

Comment: I changed it as you wrote: to QWidget and calling by exec(). I also changed setModal to this->setModal(0); Despite this the behaviour is the same and dialog behaves like to be the modal one. Please, how to correct this?

Comment: dont change anything in the modal attribute, remove the setModal line and just call exec,

Comment: This is what I also tried - I deleted setModal and call by exec(). Unfortunatelly the behaviour is the same as I described in my question. Maybe I am still missing something